# How to create a graph from a .jtl summary file programmatically?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have several .jtl files resulting from JMeter test runs and I would like to create a graph for each file. Instead of doing this manually, I would like to do this programmatically in java.

I got lost in the JMeter API and its GUI JComponent trying to figure out how this functionality is implemented.

The "Save graph" button calls saveJComponent(String filename, int type, JComponent component) in SaveGraphicsService, but I don't have a JComponent. I was expecting a set of methods to load/read jtl files, and then a GraphGenerator of some sort.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which graph do you want to get.

My suggestion will be to use `JMeter 3` feature: [Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

You can create it from `.jtl` file:

> jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard

After it, you will have a bunch of graphs generated at mentioned folder. 
Just open `index.html`.

Comment: This looks good. However, it does not work with my already existing JTL files (which lack a certain column for some reason: "No column <grpThreads> found in sample metadata").

Comment: @Tim Just follow manual for report dashboard. Probably, you missed some params during the test run. Also, I want to remind that you need to have `JMeter 3` for this. By default it doesn't have support for dashboard reporting. You have to update `user.properties` first.

Comment: @Tim Strange, I tried it in the past and if you launched JMeter script from a console with `jmeter -n -t <testplan> -l log.jtl`. Lately you able to create report dashboard from this file. However, I don't know generation when `.jtl` the file is created from a listener.

Comment: Yes, this is how I created the JTL files too: jmeter.bat -t plan.jmx -n -l results.jtl. The result headers are "timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,IdleTime,Connect" - so indeed, the <grpThreads> is missing. Don't know why. I'll try with a fresh JMeter install with default properties.

Comment: @Tim which version are you using?

Comment: The latest 3.1 Version

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of JMeter's saved files are actually in XML format; perhaps you could import the JTL file into Excel as a XML data source, and generate the graphics from there (note: untested).